# Display in line div inside legend of fieldset

Tags: html, css

I created a fielset with the following structure

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <span class="a">test</span><span class="b">test2</span><span class="c">test3</span>
     <div id="options">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
     </div>
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

I want to display div with id "options" on the same line with span.
My CSS code for legend is:

```
>legend {
        line-height: 52px;
        width:100%;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    div#options {
       display:inline;
    }
 }
```

However my div is not on the line as span. Can you help me please?

I am using lessPHP in order for CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need also define a child divs of options as inline.

```
div#options div {
    display:inline;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/oLo1dm2s/

Comment: Thank you, i thought that if parent has display:inline children will inherit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to define the display property for inner div with `id="#options"`

```
#options > div {
    display:inline;
}
```